# IoC container (место в сборке)

Tags: c#, архитектура, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control

У меня есть проект, состоящий из N слоев, на основе ASP.NET Core. Я не хочу создавать контейнер в проекте ASP.NET. Могу ли я создать контейнер в новой библиотеки классов? Если могу, то как? Если можно, приведите пример. Спасибо

Comment: Вы же на русскоязычном сайте, переведите свой вопрос на русский язык

Comment: російської не знаю, знаю українську

Comment: @DimaRoik это не повод писать на английском языке на русскоязычном сайте

Comment: Ничего страшного, что вы не знаете русский язык, тут есть [англоязычная часть сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/), вам наверное лучше задать или по крайней мере продублировать вопрос там